# Create a procedure with custom type parameters. PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I'm trying to create a procedure that's taking a record type as parameter. My problem is that i can't define my type before procedure and it say that my type is not declared.. How can i do that ?

Here is my code:

```
 type tip is record ( nume varchar(20), prenume varchar(20) );

 create or replace procedure test_procedure (a tip) as
 begin
 dbms_output.put_line(' ');
 end;
```

Error(1,29): PLS-00201: identifier 'TIP' must be declared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create a record type schema object directly. You can, however, define it in a package and use it.

Or you can define type of object instead:

```
create or replace type tip is object ( nume varchar(20), prenume varchar(20) );
```

Then use (Note that `a` is not allowed a parameter name):

```
 create or replace procedure test_procedure (p_tip tip) as
 begin
     dbms_output.put_line(. . .);
 end;
 /
```